# Is there anyway to execute React JS hook from parent in child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component "Board", there's other 3 components: TopBar, SandToHide and TreasureBoxes.

I just want that the TopBar component reads the "money" value and the TreasureBoxes executes the increment of money. The TopBar is reading the value that i'm setting in Board, but the TreasureBoxes doesn't seems to be executing the increment of the money.

Thanks in advance!

**Board/index.js**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./index.scss";
import { FaBomb, FaBox, FaFlag } from "react-icons/fa";
import img from "../../assets/ItemsToHide/barrels/barrel1.png";
import TreasureBoxes from "../TreasureBoxes";
import TopBar from '../TopBar';
import SandToHide from "../SandToHide";

const Board = ({ treasureBoxes, randomTop, randomLeft, sand}) => {
  const [money, setMoney] = useState(0);



  return (
    <div className="board-container">
      <TopBar money={money}></TopBar>
    <div className="sand-to-hide-container">
      {sand.map((sandd) => {
        return (
          <SandToHide
            id={sandd.id}
            img={sandd.img}
            randomTop={randomTop}
            randomLeft={randomLeft}
          />

        )
      })}
    </div>
    <div className="treasure-boxes-container">
    {treasureBoxes.map((box) => {
      return(
      <TreasureBoxes
        setMoney={setMoney}
        money={money} 
        id ={box.id}
        bomba = {box.bomba}
        treasureBoxes={treasureBoxes}
        randomTop={randomTop}
        randomLeft={randomLeft}
        />
      )
    })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

Comment: Try to look at `useContext` as its a global data that can be reached in all components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to have a callback in your TreasureBoxes component (it would be easier to answer to you if you provided the code for it):

```js
<input onChange={(e)=> setMoney(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: I've changed my code because it was getting too dirty, but your answer has solved the problem of this question that I've made. Thank you so much, DoneDeal0!